# How can I change the icons in Pidgin's IRC user list?

Tags: pidgin, irc

Is there any way to change the icons in the user list on IRC in Pidgin without actually doing it from the source code?

These are what I want to change:

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The icons are located in `/usr/share/pixmaps/pidgin/emblems/16`. You can open them up in an image editor  and modify them.

[image]